# Получить доступ к полям workitem (tfs api)

Tags: c#, tfs

Не удается получить доступ к полям воркайтемов описанных здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997792.aspx

в частности интересует как достучаться и изменить поля Remaining/CompletedWork. делаю так:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);
WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(id);
workItem.Fields["Description"].Value = "test";
```

и тут бы хотелось получить доступ к `CompletedWork` и сделать `workItem.Save()` но с этим возникли трудности так как такого поля нет.

Собственно вопрос:

**как получить и изменить значения этих полей?**

Comment: А в коллекции `Fields` их нет, разве?